# How do I care for my horse's well being?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

We know our horses can die, but **how can I see if it feels good or is badly wounded**?
I don't want to loose my cute little friend, **do I need to heal and feed it?**

*Oh, or ...*

> *is my Shadowmere invulnerable like back in the old times?*

Comment: "Can I see if it feels good..." Nuff said.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Shadowmere is not essential and can die, unlike his counterpart in Oblivion. However, 10 days later, he will respawn at the location of his death.

When its injured a red health bar will appears same as any other creature and no it does not need to be fed. You don't have to heal it since it can't die but if you use it as a tank then helping hands or some other healing spell will help keep it conscious.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere

Comment: She, I think. But I can confirm this.

Comment: What about the rest of the question?

Comment: When its injured a red health bar will appears same as any other creature and no it does not need to be fed. You don't have to heal it since it can't die but if you use it as a tank then helping hands or some other healing spell will help keep it conscious.

Comment: Not true, they can die... mine did!

Comment: Mine fought against a dragon ... and jumped across a cliff to attack an enemy. Didn't see a health bar anytime, too.

Comment: This answer isn't accurate. I jumped my Shadowmere off a cliff once, and I assure you the result was a dead horse.

Comment: It re-spawns at the pool where it first appears after a time.

Answer (score 7):

He can die, but it is like the NPC's it is quite hard unless you take a big fall, or you kill it yourself. Other can kill it but it requires that they try to hit you but miss, and then hit the horse in "rest" mode. In "rest" mode the bad guys will ignore the horse so just make sure that you are not close to it.

Answer (score 1):

Shadowmere cant die.

And you can use the spell wich heals allys to heal your horse if you like to.

You dont need to feed your horse.

I havent seen any possibility to see your steeds health.

Comment: shadowmere *can* die. But her health regen is ridiculously high so it takes a lot of damage all at once (fall off a mountain, for ex.) to do it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Is there source for that information? My answer is quite old and I see that I myself did not provide any.

Answer (score 1):

You can see his/her's heath if you hit it yourself, just be sure to hit him/her with your bare fists.

Answer (score 0):

Your horse CAN die, And you have to be cautious. Here's a list of ways they can die:

1. Fall off a mountain
2. Killed by wolves,bears etc
3. Killed by people( plus yourself!).

So to prevent any of this happening. Keep an eye 
Out for your buddy. Also, when you build a house, build a stable to store your horse(s). 
So there, a way to keep your horse safe, hope this helped!